# for loop indexing in python

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

What's wrong with my for loop? I am getting problem related to array indexing.

How can I fix the indexing problem inside the for loop?
  ''for sales in months:
         quarter += sales''

Create a months list, as well as an index, and set the quarter to 0

```
months = [100, 100, 150, 250 , 300, 10, 20]
quarter = 0
quarters = []
index = 0
```

Create for loop for quarter, print result, and increment the index

```
for sales in months:
  quarter += sales

  if index % 3 == 0 or index == len(months):
    quarters.append(quarter)
    quarter = 0

  index = index + 1

print("The quarter totals are Q1: {}, Q2: {}, Q3: {}".format(quarters[0], quarters[1], quarters[2]))
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Check out [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: What's the indexing problem? If you get an error, provide it in full. See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied some of the indentation wrong, but my guess is that in your code   `index = index + 1` is indented into the if block, so it will stop incrementing. You can use `enumerate` instead to avoid those kind of bugs completely.

```
for index, value in enumerate(collection):
  print(index, value) # your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
# Month sales data
month_sales = [100, 100, 150, 250, 300, 10, 20]
# Empty list to hold quarter data
quarter_sales = []
# Current quarter iteration data
quarter = 0

# Iterate over monthly sales
for index, sale in enumerate(month_sales):
    # Add month's sales to running total for the quarter
    quarter += sale
    # If last month of quarter or end of list
    if (index + 1) % 3 == 0 or index == len(month_sales) - 1:
        # Add quarter sales data to new list and start over
        quarter_sales.append(quarter)
        quarter = 0

print(f"The quarter totals are Q1: {quarter_sales[0]}, Q2: {quarter_sales[2]}, Q3: {quarter_sales[2]}")
```

There were issues with your indices

For instance `index % 3` would work if your index started at `1`, but in programming list indices start at `0`. That equates to month 3 being at index 2. Since 2 is not divisible by 3 it moves on and throws the first four months into quarter 1 and so on. You need to modify your code to account for this with `(index + 1) % 3 == 0` and also `len(month_sales) -1`